# How to show up button when scroll?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an up button.

[image: up]

I want the up button not to be seen at first, but to be seen later when a scroll is done.

And I want to replace `d-none` with `d-block`.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="position-fixed text-danger arrow-up d-none" id="scrollTop"><i class="fas fa-3x fa-chevron-circle-up"></i></a>
```

**JS**

```
if (document.getElementById('scrollTop').scrollTop === 200) {
    document.getElementById('scrollTop').classList.add('d-block');
    document.getElementById('scrollTop').classList.remove('d-none');    
}
```

Comment: On any kind of scrolling? (both up and down?) And upon how much scrolling? Any amount of scrolling? Even just one pixel of scrolling? And when should it stop being displayed? Should it be displayed forever after any scrolling is done the first time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen on scroll event. working example to show how it works:

```js
const myID = document.getElementById("myID");

var myScrollFunc = function () {
    var y = window.scrollY;
    if (y >= 800) {
        myID.className = "bottomMenu show"
    } else {
        myID.className = "bottomMenu hide"
    }
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", myScrollFunc);
```

```css
body {
    height: 2000px;
}
.bottomMenu {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    color: white;
    width: 50px;
    height: 60px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    background: red;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all .5s;
}
.hide {
    opacity:0;
   
}
.show {
    opacity:1;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="myID" class="bottomMenu hide">top</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should place your code in something like this :

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {... your code ...})
```

Comment: I replaced this code, but it did not work https://i.stack.imgur.com/vV5WQ.png